# Is this the correct explanation for this output of this program?

Tags: c, structure

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    struct test
    {
        char c;
        int y;
        float r;
        double d;
    } t1; 
    printf("%d\n",sizeof(t1));
    return 0;
}
```

Output: 
24 on my gcc 4.3.2 Ubuntu 12.04

Output: 20 on Ideone [Link for Running Code](http://ideone.com/73wNzs)

My Explanation: 
**I think 24 is right. Correct me if i am wrong ?**

1. 1st chunk will be taken by Char 'c'. 1 byte for himself followed by 3 bytes of padding.
2. 2nd chunk will be taken by Integer 'y'. (No padding required in this case as integer is of 4 byte. so it will completely fill the chunk).
3. 3rd chunk will be taken by float 'r'. (No padding required as float is of 4 bytes too).
4. Now next chunk of 4 bytes will be padded because next is double. and storage address have to multiple of size of that data type.
5. and next 2 chunk of 4 bytes each will be occupied by double variable.

Thus `Size = 1(char) + 3(Padded in Char case) + 4(int) + 4(float) + 4(padded for Double) + 8(double) = 24`

**For Clarity:**

Since Chunks are taken in 4 byte collection. so every address will be Multiple of 4.
For double , Next address has to be 1012. but it is not multiple of 8. so pad it ! and start from 1016
[image: memory layout]
**My Question - Is 24 correct and my explanation correct or my explanation is wrong else please explain ?**

Comment: Maybe neither 20 nor 24 is correct here. If you see a black cat and then a white cat, there is no reason to think that black is the "right" colour for cats for any reason.

Comment: but 24 was my answer to this question even before running code . i think 24 explains it logically too !

Comment: Alignment is implementation defined. Some compilers may add padding for the double, some may not, neither is "right". At least that's my understanding.

Comment: @TaylorBrandstetter - i think today all compiler does padding 
 putting the data at a memory offset equal to some multiple of the word size increases the system's performance due to the way the CPU handles memory.

Comment: Some machines allow `double` to be packed on a 4-byte boundary; others require `double` to be packed on an 8-byte boundary. What you describe is correct for systems where `double` must be packed on an 8-byte boundary; what ideone gives is correct for systems where `double` must be packed on a 4-byte boundary. Either could be correct for any given system, therefore. Typically, only one of them is correct. Although two different compilers on the same machine could have different structure packing rules, it is fairly unlikely to be a problem in practice -- see ABI (Application Binary Interface).

Comment: @JonathanLeffler - that is the best answer for this situation !

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is a duplicate; I've seen numerous questions here about the effect of padding on structure sizes.

Comment: The `%d` format is for `int`; for `size_t`, use `%zu`, or, if your implementation doesn't support it (it's "new" in C99), cast to `int: `printf("%d\n", (int)sizeof t1);`. And a very minor quibble: `int main()` should be `int main(void)`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your explanation is correct in the sense that the specific compiler outputs a binary with a specific layout for that struct. If you have correctly predicted the outputs, then your prediction is obviously correct **for your specific setup at this specific time**.

But the struct's size is not, *by any means*, strictly defined in C. The only thing that's defined in this subject is the order of the struct members and the offset of the first member. The padding and, therefore, **the total size of the struct is undefined** and it's left as a decision for the compiler. Obviously, the main reason a compiler would pad the struct is higher performance through proper alignment of the members based on their individual types (as you correctly noted). But (and this is important here) the compiler chooses the most efficient padding depending on the target architecture. If an architecture has a 128-bit int, for instance, you can imagine how the size of your struct would be radically different.

So, **if it comes to the defined aspects of the C language** (or to any setup other than what you described) **your prediction would be baseless**. It would naturally match *some* setups, but only by accident.

Comment: so, is it true that "Address of variable " while padding should start with multiple of sizeof that variable. because that's the only thing that affects that answer ?

Comment: @Shashank_Jain Anything could affect the answer (including compiler directives for packing the structs in a custom way). But I believe that, for the most part, what the compiler tries is to put every variable at a logical address that's a multiple of its size (as you said). However, do keep in mind that this is undefined in the language. It's very important to remember (especially for such languages as C and C++) that any conclusion based on undefined premises should be considered wrong.

Comment: C++11 does define alignment more precisely, but still makes absolutely zero guarantees about `sizeof` a struct type (except that it must be positive).

Comment: @aschepler Good to know. I'm somewhat behind in C++.

Answer (score 1):

Padding is there for using instruction optimization. C language doesn't specify anything about padding. Only problem is, if loadq (8 byte date) doesn't start at 8byte address boundary, H/W trap will happen. So, I can certainly write a compiler without any padding for this example data structure. Only problem is that I need to use loadb / storb instructions instead of loadl / storl / loadq / storq instructions which looks stupidity anyways. If Ideone is using loadl / storl instead of loadq / storq, 20 byte size is OK and the padding between float and double is not necessary.

By the way, I have a practice of declaring 8byte, 4byte, 2byte, 1byte data in that order within the structure and may be every where possible...